# Get data from click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the value in one metadata, based on event click in another metadata?

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn btn-danger"
        data-action="voltar-tela-pedidos"
        data-scroll-to="pedido-00C407948 ">
</button>

jQuery(document).on("click", '[data-action="voltar-tela-pedidos"]', function (e) {
  // i want to know the value of data-scroll-to
});
```

Comment: you have $(this) inside the jquery function, you can find all data property using $(this)

Comment: `jQuery(this)` is what you're looking for. `var myValue = jQuery(this).data('scroll-to');`

Comment: When i use this,i recive the error : $(...).data is not a function

Comment: Try: `jQuery(this).data('scroll-to');`

Comment: @RafaelUmbelino I have added to my answer an explanation as to why `$()` doesn't work and `jQuery()` does.

Comment: @RafaelUmbelino If you are interested, I also added a bit about how to find out what is loaded at the `$` global variable and if it is jQuery or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).on("click", '[data-action="voltar-tela-pedidos"]', function(e) {
    var myScrollTo = jQuery(this).data('scroll-to');
    // or
    var myScrollTo = jQuery(this).attr('data-scroll-to');
});
```

Check [demo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nq640hb8/).

```js
jQuery(document).on("click", '[data-action="voltar-tela-pedidos"]', function(e) {
  var myScrollTo1 = jQuery(this).data('scroll-to');
  // or
  var myScrollTo2 = jQuery(this).attr('data-scroll-to');
  console.log(myScrollTo1, myScrollTo2)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn btn-danger" data-action="voltar-tela-pedidos" data-scroll-to="pedido-00C407948 ">CLICK ME</button>
```

---

### `$(...).data` is not a function

> When I use this, I receive the error: `$(...).data is not a function`

When you add jQuery to your page, it ["registers itself"](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) in the global variables `$` and `jQuery`.

But those vars can be overridden.

Probably, in your web page context, `$` is not jQuery but some other lib*. In this case, always use `jQuery(...)` and not `$(...)`.

* [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) also uses the global variable `$`, which could be what is overriding jQuery. I have also seen some RichFaces/JSF based applications use `$` global variable.

---

## How to find out if `$` is jQuery?

Simply type in your console:

```
console.log($)
console.log($.fn.jquery)
```

If you `$` is jQuery, it should output something like (the second line is the jQuery version loaded):

```
// this is what stackoverflow.com prints for those commands right now. try it out.
ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
1.12.4
```

Older jQuery versions change a little, but the second command (`console.log($.fn.jquery)`) has always printed the version.

If you get an error while executing those commands, your `$` is probably some other lib. In that case, confirm that jQuery at least loaded by checking your `jQuery` variable:

```
console.log(jQuery)
console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)
```

The output should be similar to the example shown above.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).on("click", '[data-action="voltar-tela-pedidos"]', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).data("scrollTo"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-action="voltar-tela-pedidos"]').click(function() {
  var scrollTo = $(this).data("scrollTo");
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.